# Water heater busted

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

Water heater busted this morning, after a couple of hours the water was turned off at the main in the yard.

Now how can I cap off the hot water heater in order to still have water in the house, I can't get a new one until next weekend.

Please help thanks

Comment: Don't you have a cut-off valve on the cold water supply to the water heater? If not, do you have copper lines or PEX? You could cut the line and put on a Sharkbite cap.

Comment: Jim Stewart I'm checking now

Comment: Jim Stewart I see 2 copper pipe one on the left side and right side at the top of the heater and 1 water valve.

Comment: It is  often the case that the supply line going into the water heater has a shut off valve for just this reason. If you can look on top of the heater it may have labels for in and out or color codes, blue in and red out. If the valve is on the IN - side then shutting it will stop water from going into the water heater and allow the rest of the house to have the cold water supply. ( yours could be different but without more info we can not say. )

Comment: They are labeled H and the other C , however the valve on top of the C is the one that I turned off at first but that didn't stop the water from running this morning.

Comment: That valve would only shut off the hot water to the rest of the house. If the valve is turned off all the way and water still comes out of a hot water faucet then the valve is bad.

Comment: @JACK If the valve was on the H side that would be the case. It is possible that cold water is being pushed backwards into the water heater through a faucet or fixture elsewhere in the house.

Comment: Is there any way to send a picture on here? Because the valve I see looks like the kind that you would turn on for your water hose outside.

Comment: I was going to caution her on that if she said she turned the main water back on and it was leaking.

Comment: She would have to make sure all the hot water faucets were in the off position.

Comment: @Maryb as new contributor you can not ad the photo directly ( i believe )  but you can post it elsewhere and post the link then someone here can copy it  add it to your post. PLUS **ad more info on what "BUSTED" means. Ad a detailed description of what has happened**.

Comment: Jack I'll make sure to do that  thank you so much. I'm going to try this.

Comment: The hot water heater just started pouring water out every where and from just looking at it , it appeared that the water was coming from the bottom panel on the front of the heater at this point I knew to flip the pressure valve and the water started to flow outside however it was still pouring in the house after calling around for help I was told to hook up the water hose and that helped then we got someone to turn the water off at the main in the yard.

Comment: Have you tried to turn the water main back on after turning the valve at the water heater off and making sure all the faucets are in the off position?

Comment: Jack yes sir  and I got some pvc pipe , plumber glue and capped it off turned the water back on from the main and I have cold water no leaks. I Just finished up thank you sooooooooo much for your time and advice.

Comment: Now you're an expert and can help people on this site when they have a water tank issue. You take care.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off the valve at the hot water heater will stop the leak while no faucets are in use. If you only use cold water everything will be ok but if a single handle valve is turned on with some hot and cold the cold water pressure can return to the water heater and the leak may start again.  Make sure to only use cold water and turn off the supply water and gas/ electrical to the water heater, no reason to waste $ on a broken heater